# Extending Lumen's web routes file

Tags: laravel, lumen

By the docs, it is stated that routes should be placed in `web/routes.php`. I wonder, can I organize the routes by class or modules the way I wanted?

Comment: Can you add more information about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in my lumen 5.4 app. For each module/controller class I have a different `Route.php` file under `App\Http\Routes\`. And in my `App\Http\routes.php`, I load them as

```
$app->group(
    [],
    function () use ($app) {
        foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/Routes/*.php') as $filename) {
            include $filename;
        }
    }
);
```